# better way to check last element in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to do this: check if `callback` is supplied, so I do it as follow. What I want to know is:

1. can I check last element simplier?
2. in fact this may fail in some situation: if last element is a function but it is not the callbak.

Here is the code

```
_deferred = Q.defer()
[before..., last] = args
if typeof last is 'function'
    args = before
    cb = last
else
  cb = (err, results) ->
      if err?
          _deferred.reject(err)
      else
          _deferred.resolve(results)
// ... other code
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter version is to "split" the args in the function parameters list:

```
fn = (args..., cb) ->
    _deferred = Q.defer()

    # if cb is a function, it gets assigned to callback
    # and we skip the following statements because not (true and true) == false
    if not (typeof cb is 'function' and callback = cb)
        # cb is not a function so it's just another arg
        args.push cb
        callback = (err, results) ->
            if err? then _deferred.reject(err) else _deferred.resolve(results)

    console.log args
    console.log callback.toSource() # Function.toSource() only works on Firefox
    # ... other code

fn 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', () -> 'foo'
```

About your second question, only you know what a "true" callback is or not. If you can't decide it by the type, you could change your fn parameters format, for example, pass an object:

```
params =
    callback: () -> 'foo'
    args: [ 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', () -> 'bar' ]

fn2 = ({ callback, args }) ->
    callback = callback or (err, results) ->
        if err? then _deferred.reject(err) else _deferred.resolve(results)

    console.log args
    console.log callback.toSource() # again, this only works in Firefox


fn2(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cb = args.pop() # cb will be the last element, args will contain the rest
if typeof cb isnt 'function' or cb.length isnt 2 # as a partial solution
    cb = (err, results) ->
      ...
```